# search records by user in the scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to search all the records where `IdEmpresa`: `current_usuario.empresa_id` 
the scope is this:

```
scope :por_empresa, -> { where(IdEmpresa: current_usuario.empresa_id) }
```

But I get this error:

> undefined local variable or method current_usuario' for
>   Vendedor(Table doesn't exist):Class Did you mean? current_scope

Can I not call the `current_user` in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not call `current_user` in model. This helper is only available in controllers/views.

You can change the scope to accept an argument:

```
scope :por_empresa, ->(user) { where(IdEmpresa: user.empresa_id) }
```

Now you can use it in controller as follows (passing the `current_user` object as an argument to scope):

```
Model.por_empresa(current_user)
```

Of course you can optimize it a bit by passing only user's `id`:

```
scope :por_empresa, ->(user_id) { where(IdEmpresa: user_id) } # model
Model.por_empresa(current_user.id)                            # usage
```

P.S. it looks like a bad practice to me having non-english words in your code base..